# ip link set command throws error.RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, ip, tun

I am using linux mint.I want to set up a tun virtual Ethernet device.
sudo ip tuntap add dev tun0 mod tun
sudo ip address add 192.168.82.22/24 dev tun0
sudo ip link set dev tun0 address 54:e1:ad:b9:12:ee
the last command throws out a exception:RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
who can help me ?thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, is this by any chance run in a container?

Comment: I ran it on my local pc,not a virtual machine